# Is there a website that keeps track of which software versions are available in which distributions?

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I want to find out and keep track of which package versions I should support when writing software for other people to install and use.

There is a website (https://caniuse.com) that helps you find out which features are available in which browsers. In a similar fashion, I would like to find out which software versions are available in different distributions.

Comment: @Jesse_b I extended the question: explained what caniuse.com does and what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Jesse_b I have changed the title to not mention the website. I don't see the point in not mentioning it at all.

Comment: @curusarn: I sort of agree, however as your question was originally written it really seemed like a facade with the intent of promoting this website.  It's always best to try and explain all questions without requiring users to redirect to another potentially harmful website.

Comment: @ThomasDickey It does, thanks.